# Spotify malformed json error in laravel php http put request

Tags: php, laravel, api, request, spotify

I am trying to send a put request to the spotify player endpoint. The documentation for it states that the device id should be sent as a json array that includes one device id.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/transfer-a-users-playback

I have tried several variations to get this to work as a laravel http request. All other API calls I make have worked fine but since this one is expecting a specific format I can't seem to get ti right.

Below are two different way I tried to send this data, The devices2 I copy and pasted the example format from the developer reference and then replaced with my device ID and yet it still does not work.

Any advice for what I am missing would be appreciated.

```
$devices = json_encode([
    "device_ids" => [$deviceId]
]);

$devices2 = '{"device_ids":["'.$deviceId.'"]}';

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
])->put('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player', ["device_ids" => $devices]);

$data = $response->json();
```

Comment: This is what the Spotify document asks `{device_ids:["74ASZWbe4lXaubB36ztrGX"]}` and this is what you send `{device_ids:{device_ids:["74ASZWbe4lXaubB36ztrGX"]}}`

Seems like changing the second argument of put and adding only the `$devices` variable there  can solve your problem